# Как динамически добавить атрибуты для <li> пришедшие по ajax

Tags: jquery

Помогите разобраться в таком вопросе.

По ajax get-ом приходят данные в виде json. Мне нужно после прихода данных вставить в список элементы  c атрибутами. Должно получиться так

```
 <ul>
    <li id="1">Первый</li>
    <li id="2">Второй</li>
    <li id="3">Третий</li>
 </ul>
```

Данные я вставляю так

```
$.each(data, function(index, element){

 $('.category ul').append('<li>' + element.category + '</li>');

});
```

Так же приходят в данных id как бы добавить эти айдишки для каждого < li >

Comment: Попробуйте `.text()`

Comment: `id` не должны начинаться с цифры. Могут возникнуть ошибки

Comment: Спасибо за поправочку. id конечно же будут другие это я для примера тут написал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте отдельным элементом, а там уже обращайтесь к нему:

```
$.each(data, function(index, element){
  var li = $('<li></li>').html( element.category ).attr('id', element.id);

  $('.category ul').append( li );
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! абсолютно то что надо.